# Understanding Lodash - findwhere and copy operator in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, lodash

Can someone help me understand why Lodash when it fetches a object using findWhere does a reference copy which enables me to bind the whole variable to the scope and change it dynamically based on user action. 
But the same operation when done using copy operator fails to update the source object. I have put out a plunker 
http://plnkr.co/edit/Phy5xQnGBYsBnenMQHOd?p=preview

HTML CODE:

```
<html ng-app="angularjs-starter">

  <head lang="en">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Custom Plunker for service response data binding</title>
    <script data-require="lodash.js@2.4.1" data-semver="2.4.1" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/2.4.1/lodash.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.3/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <input type="text" data-ng-model="inputModel" />
    <input type="text" data-ng-model="inputModel2.desc" />
    <button data-ng-click="btnClick()">Click me and check console</button>
  </body>

</html>
```

JS CODE:

```
var app = angular.module('angularjs-starter', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope,$http) {
  var someServiceResponse = [{"code":"1","desc":"apple"},{"code":"2","desc":"orange"}];
  $scope.inputModel = someServiceResponse[0].desc;
  $scope.inputModel2 = _.findWhere(someServiceResponse,{'code':'2'});
  $scope.btnClick = function(){
    console.log($scope.inputModel);//Outputs the changed value in the text box1
    console.log($scope.inputModel2.desc);//Outputs the changed value in the text box2
    console.log(someServiceResponse[0].desc); // Still shows the old value from the service response - always shows apple
    console.log(someServiceResponse[1].desc); // shows updated value from second text box
  };
});
```

Comment: For me the last two console.logs always show apple and orange.

Comment: Absor - Apologies! my bad. I have updated the question as well as plunker.

Comment: inputModel is a reference to a string, if it is updated the reference will be set to a new string. inputModel2 is a reference to an object and you update desc string inside it.

Comment: but i dint quite get it !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Background**:

Service has a variable object Object1, Object1 has a variable String2 that is a reference to a string.

Object1 points a to memory location 1, variable String2 points to memory location 2 that contains the string.

```
Object = {}
Object1.String2 = ""
Object1 -> 1
Object1.String2 -> 2
```

**Case 1:**

Controller has a variable String3 that is set to Object1.String2 that is asked from service.

String3 now points to memory address 2 that contains the string.

Controller changes String3 value when new data comes from view. String3 now points to memory location 3. Object1 variable String2 still points to 2 as we didn't modify Object1 variable, we modified variable String3.

```
String3 = Object1.String2
String3 -> 2
Object1 -> 1
Object1.String2 -> 2

String3 = "changed"
String3 -> 3
Object1 -> 1
Object1.String2 -> 2
```

**Case 2:**

Controller has a variable Object2 that is set to Object1 that is asked from service.

Object2 now points to memory address 1 that contains the object.

Controller changes Object2.String2 value when new data comes from view. Object2.String2 now points to memory location 3. Object2 refered to the Object1 so Object1.String2 was actually modified to point to memory location 3. As the service has a reference to Object1 it is actually "updated to service".

```
Object2 = Object1
Object2 -> 1
Object1 -> 1
Object1.String2 -> 2

Object2.String2 = "changed"
Object2 -> 1
Object1 -> 1
Object1.String2 -> 3
```